# Populate DTO using query with JOIN

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I have this main `Product` table:

```
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 20)
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 75)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "meta_title", length = 100)
    private String metaTitle;

    @Column(name = "status", length = 100)
    private String status;
}
```

Additional table for storing categories that should be returned as List:

```
@Table(name = "product_category")
public class ProductCategory implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "product_id", length = 4)
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name = "category_id", length = 20)
    private Integer categoryId;

}
```

Additional table for storing Payment Methods that should be returned as List:

```
@Table(name = "product_payment_methods")
public class ProductPaymentMethods implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "product_id", length = 20)
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name = "payment_methods", length = 20000)
    private String paymentMethods;
}
```

I want to return a result like this:

```
id | title | categoryId | paymentMethods |
1  | test  |    34, 43  |    345, 7, 5   |
5  | test2 |    64,5, 3 |    654, 3, 5   |
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
INNER JOIN product_category ON Product.id = product_category.productId
INNER JOIN product_payment_methods ON Product.id = product_payment_methods.productId
WHERE userId = 1
```

What is the proper way to populate this DTO?

```
public class ProductFullDTO {
   private int id;

   private Integer userId;

   private List<Integer> categories;

   private List<String> paymentMethods;
}
```

Comment: You're using JPA wrong, you should map the relationships between entities with annotations (ex: @OneToMany) and use class entities instead of integer ids (`Product product`, instead of `Integer productId`). This way, the JPA implementor will generate required joins behind the curtains (optimization is another problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as indicated in your comments, you need query your information with HQL a good way to proceed can be the following.

First, modify your `Product` entity an include relationships for both `ProductCategory` and `ProductPaymentMethods`, something like:

```java
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 20)
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 75)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "meta_title", length = 100)
    private String metaTitle;

    @Column(name = "status", length = 100)
    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ProductCategory> categories;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List< ProductPaymentMethods> paymentMethods;

    // Setters and getters, omitted for brevity
}
```

Modify both `ProductCategory` and `ProductPaymentMethods` to accommodate the entities relationship:

```java
@Table(name = "product_category")
public class ProductCategory implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    // Please, feel free to change the insertable and updatable attributes to 
    // fit your needs
    @Column(name = "product_id", length = 4, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer productId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "category_id", length = 20)
    private Integer categoryId;

    // Setters and getters, omitted for brevity

}

@Table(name = "product_payment_methods")
public class ProductPaymentMethods implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    // Please, feel free to change the insertable and updatable attributes to 
    // fit your needs. By the way, why here the length is 20 and not 4?
    @Column(name = "product_id", length = 20, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Integer productId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "payment_methods", length = 20000)
    private String paymentMethods;
}
```

With this setup, as you can see in the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) - it is for an old Hibernate version, but it is correct today, you can use fetch joins to obtain the required information:

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select. This is particularly useful in the case of a collection.

For your example, consider the following HQL (assume outer join semantics, modify it as appropriate):

```java
select product
from Product as product
     left join fetch product.categories
     left join fetch product.paymentMethods
where product.userId = 1
```

This will provide you the list of products for `userId` `1`, with all the associated references to categories and payment methods initialized.

The conversion between the entity and the DTO should be straightforward:

```java
Session session = ...
List<Product> products = session.createQuery(
    "select product " +
    "from Product as product " +
    "     left join fetch product.categories " +
    "     left join fetch product.paymentMethods " +
    "where product.userId = :userId", Product.class)
.setParameter( "userId", 1)
.getResultList();

List<ProductFullDTO> productFullDTOs = null;
if (products != null) {
  productFullDTOs = products.stream()
      .map((product -> {
        ProductFullDTO productFullDTO = new ProductFullDTO();
        productFullDTO.setId(product.getId());
        productFullDTO.setUserId(product.getUserId());
        
        List<ProductCategory> categories = product.getCategories();
        if (categories != null) {
          List<Integer> categoriesIds = categories.stream()
              .map(ProductCategory::getCategoryId)
              .collect(Collectors.toList())
          ;
          
          productFullDTO.setCategories(categoriesIds);
        }

        List<ProductPaymentMethods> paymentMethods = product.getPaymentMethods();
        if (paymentMethods != null) {
          List<String> paymentMethodsIds = paymentMethods.stream()
              .map(ProductPaymentMethods::getPaymentMethods)
              .collect(Collectors.toList())
          ;

          productFullDTO.setPaymentMethods(paymentMethodsIds);
        }
        
        return productFullDTO;
      }))
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
  ;
}

System.out.println(productFullDTOs == null ? "No products found." : productFullDTOs.size() + " products found.");
```

Comment: Can you add a section about conversion between the entity and the DTO, please?

Comment: Of course. I updated the answer with the information. I hope it helps.

Comment: Did it help Peter?

Answer (score 1):

You should use TypeHandler to finish this job. I just give paymentMethods as example.

```
    @Results({
            @Result(column = "product.id", property = "id"),
            @Result(column = "user_id", property = "userId"),
            @Result(column = "category_id", property = "categories"),
            @Result(column = "payment_methods", property = "paymentMethods" ,typeHandler= StrListTypeHandler.class),
    })
    @Select("SELECT * FROM Product INNER JOIN product_category ON Product.id = product_category.productId "
        + " INNER JOIN product_payment_methods ON Product.id = product_payment_methods.productId "
        + " WHERE userId = 1")
    List<ProductFullDTO> getProduct();

// the below is TypeHandler implementation
@Component
public class StrListTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, List<String> strings, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (String s : strings) {
            sb.append(s).append(",");
        }
        preparedStatement.setString(i, sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 1));
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getResult(ResultSet resultSet, String s) throws SQLException {
        String[] arr = resultSet.getString(s).split(",");
        return Arrays.asList(arr);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        String[] arr = resultSet.getString(i).split(",");
        return Arrays.asList(arr);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
        String[] arr = callableStatement.getString(i).split(",");
        return Arrays.asList(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can  you show me how I can implement this SQL query into HQL, please?

Comment: I am not familiar with hibernate. Maybe you can write a class extends AliasedTupleSubsetResultTransformer of hibernate to implement result by yourself. here is a sample: http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/hibernate/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java.shtml